# Ноутбук видит наушники но нету звука Windows 10

Tags: windows, аудио

Сидел я за ноутом Lenovo Legion 5, смотрел фильм в наушниках, накрыл ноут, поел, вернулся к ноуту, открыл, а звука в наушниках уже не было. Прошу напомнить если я что-то забыл, либо посоветовать сдать в ремонт

0. Ноут перегружал не раз
1. Динамик ноутбука работают
2. Наушники работают (проверял на другом устройстве)
3. ПКМ по значку динамиков на панели задач -> звуки -> вкладка "Воспроизведение", наушники являются устройством по умолчанию
4. В этом же меню возле всех включенных устройств есть ползунок который показывает уровень громкости этих устройств. При включении звука, ползунок возле наушников РЕАГИРУЕТ на звук
5. В диспетчере устройств перегружал и откатывал все аудиоустройства и порты
6. Комп на вирусы проверял

Не думаю что дело в драйверах, так как динамики тогда тоже не работали бы. Посоветуйте какое-то решение?

Comment: Не HP часом? Такая же бодяга была...

Comment: Не, Lenovo Legion 5. 2 месяца как куплен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После очередной восьми тысячной перезагрузки звук наконец-то появился

Comment: Может быть проблема с нестабильными драйверами. Попробуйте обновить.